# VBSCRIPT slow under Windows Feature Update 1803

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, windows-10

My company still has a classic asp site that we are working to upgrade to .net.  Our entire development team ground to a halt when we upgraded to windows feature 1803 which introduced task view.  A single page went from a few seconds to over 8 minutes to load. Since classic asp and VBScript are not popular there was nothing about this on stack overflow.

I found the fix and wanted to leave this info here in case anyone else also is having this issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Helped us enormously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the vbscript.dll file from a pre-1803 feature branch of windows and copy it to your updated machine.  I did this in two locations c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\SysWOW64.  Not sure if both were needed, but my page load time went from 8+minutes to under 10 seconds.

I recommend keeping your original dll just in case.

You will need to change the owner of the file from Trusted Installer to Administrators to grant yourself the permission to touch the file.